# Bash/Hive: Adding a field to each rwo of a 2D array

Tags: bash, hive

I am running a hive query through a bash script.

```
out=$(hive -e "query here;")
```

And the result is:

```
val1 val2
```

Normally I run the following command to add the date:

```
echo "`eval date +%Y%m%d`     $out"
```

And the result comes out as:

```
20150714 val1 val2
```

However, when I `Group By` a field, `out` is a 2D array as expected:

```
g1  val1g1  val2g1
g2  val1g2  val2g2
g3  val1g3  val2g3
```

However, I need to add the date field to each of the rows now.

The previous command gives me the following answer:

```
20150714    g1  val1g1  val2g1
g2  val1g2  val2g2
g3  val1g3  val2g3
```

Any easy way to fix this?

Comment: why not `hive -e "query here;" | awk -v myDate=$(date +%Y%m%d) {print myDate " " $0}'` Good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted, Voting up, and glad you have 2 solutions now. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter. However this just converts the 2D array to a linear vector with `myDate` prepended. That doesn't resolve my problem. I want it to remain a 2D array and want to write this to a file via `>> output`

Answer (score 1):

Unix_timestamp() will work.  Wrap it in from_unixtime to make it readable.

```
hive -e "select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as date, col1, col2 from table;"
```

Comment: Thanks @invoketheshell for taking the time to respond. This will probably work for this specific case of the date, however, as the title suggests, my question about adding an arbitrary field to the 2D array. (I had given hive query only as a reference for background.)